# Declaring Lifetime of Closure in Struct

Tags: rust, lifetime

From the various sources I can find, giving a lifetime to a property in a `struct` would be done like so:

```
pub struct Event<'self> {
    name: String,
    execute: &'self |data: &str|
}
```

Use of the `&'self` lifetime is now deprecated.  When declaring a property to be a closure type, the compiler tells me it needs a lifetime specifier, but I cannot find an example anywhere that has a closure as a property of a struct.

This is what I am currently trying:

```
pub struct Event<'a> {
    name: String,
    execute: &'a |data: &str|
}
```

But I get the following error: `error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]`

What is the proper syntax for declaring a lifetime of a `closure` in a `struct`, or any type for that matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Updated to Rust 1.4.

Closures are now based on one of three traits, [`Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), and [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html).

The type of a closure cannot be defined precisely, we can only bound a generic type to one of the closure traits.

```
pub struct Event<F: Fn(&str) -> bool> {
    name: String,
    execute: F
}
```

Comment: The asymmetry is somewhat jarring :/

Comment: When I try that, I get ``error: expected type, found `|` ``. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: How do I do that if I'm already trying to make the struct generic over two types, and I want the closure type to be defined in terms of those types?